# EF Core 2.1 GROUP BY and select first item in each group

Tags: c#, group-by, entity-framework-core

Let's imaging a forum having a list of topics and posts in them.
I want to get the list of topics and a title of last post (by date) for each topic.

Is there a way to achieve this using EF Core (2.1)?
In SQL it could be done like

```
SELECT Posts.Title, Posts.CreatedDate, Posts.TopicId FROM 
  (SELECT Max(CreatedDate), TopicId FROM Posts GROUP BY TopicId) lastPosts
JOIN Posts ON Posts.CreatedDate = lastPosts.CreatedDate AND Posts.TopicId = lastPosts.TopicId
```

In EFCore I can select LastDates

```
_context.Posts.GroupBy(x => x.TopicId, (x, y) => new
            {
                CreatedDate = y.Max(z => z.CreatedDate),
                TopicId = x,
            });
```

And if I run .ToList() the query is correctly translated to `GROUP BY`.
But I can't go further.
The following is executed in memory, not in SQL (resulting in `SELECT * FROM Posts`):

```
            .GroupBy(...)
            .Select(x => new
            {
                x.TopicId,
                Post = x.Posts.Where(z => z.CreatedDate == x.CreatedDate)
                //Post = x.Posts.FirstOrDefault(z => z.CreatedDate == x.CreatedDate)
            })
```

Attempting to JOIN gives NotSupportedException (Could not parse expression):

```
.GroupBy(...)
.Join(_context.Posts,
                    (x, y) => x.TopicId == y.TopicId && x.CreatedDate == y.CreatedDate,
                    (x, post) => new
                    {
                        post.Title,
                        post.CreatedDate,
                    })
```

I know I can do it using SELECT N+1 (running a separate query per topic), but I'd like to avoid that.

Comment: found http://tsherlock.tech/2018/03/20/joining-in-memory-list-to-entity-framework-query/ which could help here, but still pure EF solution is better, if there's one

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I don't know since which version of EFCore it's possible, but there's a simpler single-query alternative now:

```
context.Topic
   .SelectMany(topic => topic.Posts.OrderByDescending(z => z.CreatedDate).Take(1),
        (topic, post) => new {topic.Id, topic.Title, post.Text, post.CreatedDate})
   .OrderByDescending(x => x.CreatedDate)
   .ToList();
```

Answer (score 14):

Basically what I'm doing now is after running

```
var topics = _context.Posts.GroupBy(x => x.TopicId, (x, y) => new
            {
                CreatedDate = y.Max(z => z.CreatedDate),
                TopicId = x,
            }).ToList();
```

I build the following query:

```
Expression<Func<Post, bool>> lastPostsQuery = post => false;
foreach (var topic in topics) 
{
    lastPostsQuery = lastPostsQuery.Or(post => post.TopicId == topic.TopicId && post.CreatedDate = topic.CreatedDate); //.Or is implemented in PredicateBuilder
}
var lastPosts = _context.Posts.Where(lastPostsQuery).ToList();
```

Which results in one query (instead of N) like `SELECT * FROM Posts WHERE (Posts.TopicId == 1 AND Posts.CreatedDate = '2017-08-01') OR (Posts.TopicId == 2 AND Posts.CreatedDate = '2017-08-02') OR ...`.

Not extremely efficient but since the number of topics per page is quite low it does the trick.

Comment: "Not extremely efficient"... More like extremely inefficient

Answer (score 3):

In EF Core 2.1 GroupBy LINQ operator only support translating to the SQL GROUP BY clause in most common cases. Aggregation function like sum, max ...

[**linq-groupby-translation**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-2.1#linq-groupby-translation)

You can until full support group by in EF Core use [**Dapper**](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper)

Comment: I actually was using https://github.com/ethanli83/EFSqlTranslator (since EFCore 1.1) before attempting to migrate to built-in GroupBy.

Answer (score -1):

**I am not sure about version of EFCore it's possible, but you can try something like this:** It will first group by then will select max id and return max id record from each group.

```
var firstProducts = Context.Posts
.GroupBy(p => p.TopicId)
.Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(p => p.id).FirstOrDefault())
.ToList();
```